# Laravel noun1/$arg1/noun2/$arg2 routing/controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I would like to have the following url:

```
http://localhost/question/1/choices/
```

and optionally /question/1/choices/3

Where 1 is a question_id and 3 is a choice_id.

How can I do that in Laravel?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I think I could achieve this with something like

```
Route::get('questions/(:num)/choices/(:num)')
```

But how can I link it to the controller

```
Class Questions extends Base_Controller {
    public static $restful = TRUE;
    public function get_choices($question_id, $choice_id) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Laravel.  And what have you tried?  There's lots of information about routing in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#wildcards)

Comment: I'm using Laravel 3. The doc is very helpful but I wasn't able to find what I was looking for in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you'll want a `Questions_Controller` (remember the `_Controller`, it's important) like this:

```php
// controllers/questions.php
class Questions_Controller extends Base_Controller {
    public $restful = true;
    public function get_choices($question_id, $choice_id)
    {
        // Use $question_id and $choice_id
    }
}
```

And your route would look like `controller@action`, so...

```php
// routes.php
Route::get('questions/(:num)/choices/(:num)', 'questions@choices');
```

Routing to actions is covered at the end of [Controller Routing](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#controller-routing), just before the section on [CLI Route Testing](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#cli-route-testing).  Wildcards work the same with actions as they do anonymous functions.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is the missing link I'm looking for. Yeah, I forgot to add the _Controller at the end of the name class in my example. I was hoping I could it with just Route::controller(arraY('questions')); in my route but it seems it cannot.

Comment: Route::controller('questions'); would allow you to have routes like `questions/choices/(:num)/(:num)`, anything that breaks the `controller/action/param*` pattern needs to be routed manually.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel allows you to use nested resources.. 
In your case you could have the following in your routes.php

```
Route::resource('question', 'QuestionController');
Route::resource('question.choices', 'ChoicesController');
```

Then in your ChoicesController be sure to pass in both question_Id and choice_Id

You can check if everything is routed correctly by running:

```
php artisan routes
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I've read about nested routes but I haven't found that example code. By the way, I'm using Laravel 3. I tried running php artisan routes but it couldn't find that task.

Comment: My bad... I should have mentioned that this a Laravel 4 feature and isn't available in v3. Instead you could do as @phill-sparks has answered.

Although a Laravel 4 stable release has been announced to be released this month, so you might want to consider upgrading at some point if feasable. Lots of great new features to take advantage of!

Comment: My fault, I forgot to mention I'm using Laravel 3. Yeah, been checking Laravel 4 news lately but I can't wait for the release. I would however use it in my next projects.